# Implementing Lightning App for an org with some classic users and some lightning experience users

Tags: lightning-apps, lightning-experience, navigation, salesforce-classic

I have built a new lightning application that allows users to complete a certain process that is defined by the business.

If I was building this purely for classic users, I would embed the lightning app into  Visualforce Page and use either  formula field or a detail button to open the page in a new tab (this is the outcome I am looking for). However, roughly half of the users in this org are currently using Lightning Experience which I am not nearly as familiar with.

This question comes with 2 parts:

a) is there a way for me to implement that if you are in classic it will open the VF page with the lightning app embedded, and if you are in lightning it will open the lightning app?

b) how do you navigate from a standard page to a lightning app in the lightning experience whilst still displaying the header (Salesforce logos and tabs etc)?

Hopefully someone can help me out. Lightning applications are a brilliant way to build applications but it is not much use to me if it is this difficult to implement

This is unique to the similar question that exists as it advises to use SLDS with a Visualforce page, however I have developed an actual lightning app using lightning component. Whether I render the wrapper VF page, the direct VF page OR straight to the lightning app URL it never displays the header and side bar in the Lightning Experience. The simple question would be how do I navigate from a standard record to a lightning app that is built to perform a process on the data within that record, whilst maintaining the header and sidebar?

Comment: Read all answers in the duplicate question as there are now several ways to do it including this link in the comments: http://peterknolle.com/lightning-components-in-visualforce/

Comment: this question is NOT a duplicate as the post above uses SLDS within a vf page but does not use a lightning app. I have never come across a similar question to this one therefor it is not a duplicate!

Comment: Read the comment and this ink in the comment above. It uses a lightning component in a vf page